# Update statement to deduct from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables: `product` and  `sale`.  How can I write a SQL statement to deduct sale item from a product?

I tried

```
UPDATE product,
       sale 
   SET product = ( product.ProductQuantity - sale.quantity)
```

Comment: your item is quite unclear. You should specify table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this SQL statement

```
UPDATE product SET productquantity=(productquantity-(SELECT quantity FROM sale)) WHERE product_id={ some product id }
```

I added WHERE `product_id={ some product id }` as you probably want to update specific product only

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which value you are trying to update, you must specify the following:

```
UPDATE T1,T2 SET T1.Field = (T1.Field - T2.Field)
```

You were very close, however you must specify the field to update (where your product is)